# From sleep_on() to wait_event()?

Tags: linux, synchronization, kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm porting legacy code from Linux 3.14 to 4.1. There are dozens of calls to `sleep_on()` functions that I need to convert to calls to `wait_event()` functions:

```
wait_event(wq, condition);
wait_event_interruptible(wq, condition);
wait_event_timeout(wq, condition, timeout);
wait_event_interruptible_timeout(wq, condition, timeout);
```

The `sleep_on()` functions were removed in kernel 3.15 because they cause race conditions.

My problem is it will take a lot of time to understand the tricky code that uses the `sleep_on()` functions and make proper changes, test, etc. and I need to release at least a prototype as soon as possible. And consider I'm a Linux device drivers newbie.

Do you know a pattern I could use to replace calls to `sleep_on()` functions by calls to `wait_event()` functions? For example, if I just replace `sleep_on(&wait_queue)` by `wait_event(wait_queue, false)`, what will be the impact compared to the legacy code? Will the result be as bad as the legacy code (can have race conditions), or much worse?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define `sleep_on` function as it has been defined in pre-3.15 kernels. Like this:

```
void
sleep_on(wait_queue_head_t *q)
{
    unsigned long flags;
    wait_queue_t wait;

    init_waitqueue_entry(&wait, current);

    __set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE);

    spin_lock_irqsave(&q->lock, flags);
    __add_wait_queue(q, &wait);
    spin_unlock(&q->lock);
    schedule();
    spin_lock_irq(&q->lock);
    __remove_wait_queue(q, &wait);
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&q->lock, flags);
}
```

(originated from the code of `sleep_on_common` but with timeout things removed.)

For those who want to see the original code on kernel.org, see `sleep_on_common()` with commit `32d01dc7be4e725ab85ce1d74e8f4adc02ad68dd` in April 2014 (a few days before the function was removed).

---

As for `wait_event()` and friends, using *constant condition* is wrong:

- 'true' will never sleep
- 'false' will never woken up